# Make a button hidden when body has class name "dark"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons one makes the theme dark and the other one makes the theme light I want the dark button hides when body has class name "dark" and the light button be hidden when body has class name "light".

Thank you.

Comment: You can use CSS for that, for example `.dark button.make-it-dark { display: none }`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to always include a [mcve] in your question so that people can give you specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this using CSS. Let's say you have buttons like this in your HTML:

```
<body class="light">
  <button class="btn-light">Light</button>
  <button class="btn-dark">Dark</button>
</body>
```

The CSS to make the appropriate buttons hidden depending on body class is this:

```
body.light button.btn-dark {
  display: none;
}

body.dark button.btn-light {
  display: none;
}
```